# Find the probability using the normal approximation to the binomial

Tags: probability

Studies show that 7 percent of the labour force in Australia is between 16 and 24 years old. Using the normal approximation to the binomial, find the probability that a random sample of 200 employed persons in Australia contains 10 or fewer in the 16 to 24 age group. Use the continuity correction.

(a) 0.334

(b) 0.166

(c) 0.1335

(d) 0.834

(e) 0.3665

How do I do this?

Comment: It has been over three years. Would you consider deleting this question post or accept the answer to wrap it up? I assume you have already got your answer here or elsewhere and moved on.

Comment: Hello? Are you there. Again, please accept the answer and "conclude" this post.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The expression is

$$ P(X\leq 10)\approx\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-\mu}{\sqrt{n\cdot p\cdot (1-p)}} \right)=\Phi\left( \frac{10+0.5-0.07\cdot 200}{\sqrt{200\cdot 0.07\cdot 0.93}} \right)$$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution and $0.5$ the continuity correction factor.